Trying to Connect to SharePoint from Python unsuccessfully
All of the setup on the Sharepoint side gave me the connection details.  Here is my Python that I can't get to work. Dummy values used in the example.
import json
from office365.runtime.auth.client_credential import ClientCredential
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext
from office365.runtime.auth.authentication_context import AuthenticationContext

# Function to get secrets (replace with your method of fetching secrets)
def get_secret(secret_name):
    # Mock function to simulate retrieving secrets
    return json.dumps({
        "SHAREPOINT_SITE_URL": "aaaaa",
        "SHAREPOINT_CLIENT_ID": "bbbb",
        "SHAREPOINT_CLIENT_SECRET": "ccccc",
        "TENANT_ID": "dddd"
    })

def connect_to_sharepoint():
    try:
        # Fetch connection data
        sp_conn_data = json.loads(get_secret("test"))
        
        # Extract connection details
        sp_site = sp_conn_data["SHAREPOINT_SITE_URL"]
        sp_client = sp_conn_data["SHAREPOINT_CLIENT_ID"]
        sp_secret = sp_conn_data["SHAREPOINT_CLIENT_SECRET"]
        tenant_id = sp_conn_data["TENANT_ID"]         

        # Authenticate to SharePoint
        authority_url = f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}"
        auth_context = AuthenticationContext(authority_url)
        client_credential = ClientCredential(sp_client, sp_secret)
        token_response = auth_context.acquire_token_for_app(sp_site, client_credential)
        
        if not token_response:
            raise Exception(auth_context.get_last_error())
        
        access_token = token_response['accessToken']
        ctx = ClientContext(sp_site).with_access_token(access_token)
        
        # Test the connection
        web = ctx.web
        ctx.load(web)
        ctx.execute_query()

        print(f"Connected to SharePoint site: {web.properties['Title']}")
        
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error connecting to SharePoint: {str(e)}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    connect_to_sharepoint()

I keep getting this error but have tried multiple connection approaches.
Error connecting to SharePoint: 'AuthenticationContext' object is not subscriptable

